# alert me that it is already selected if i select the same value of two dropdown option and one search list the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        <div class="container" style="padding-top:70px;">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4>Transfer Batch</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title"></label>
                                </div>
                               <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                    <label for="title">From Sub-location:</label>
                                    <select id="from_sub_location"   class="form-control" style="width:350px">
                                        <option value="0">SELECT</option>
                                        <option value="1">Reception principale</option>
                                        <option value="2">Reception Alle Maternite</option>
                                        <option value="3">Reception Alle Pediatriqui</option>
                                        <option value="4">Reception immigration</option>
                                        <option value="5">Carte de credit</option>
                                        <option value="6">2e etage</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                    <label for="title">To sub-location:</label>
                                    <select id="to_sub_location"  class="form-control" style="width:350px">
                                        <option value="0">SELECT</option>
                                        <option value="1">Reception principale</option>
                                        <option value="2">Reception Alle Maternite</option>
                                        <option value="3">Reception Alle Pediatriqui</option>
                                        <option value="4">Reception immigration</option>
                                        <option value="5">Carte de credit</option>
                                        <option value="6">2e etage</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" id="medicineSearchBar" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." >
                                </div>
                                <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
                                <ul style="width:100%; max-height:300px; overflow-y: scroll;" id="li-psearch" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"
                                    aria-labelledby="menu1">
                                    <li role="presentation" class="divider-search"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="card">
                    <table id="myclass" class="table table-bordered">

                                    <tr id="mainTable">
                                        <th scope="col">From</th>
                                        <th scope="col">To</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Reagent Name</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Expiry Date</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tbody id="results_body">


                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;margin: 4px 2px;">Transfer</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    @include('includes.foot')
                    <meta name="loc" content="{{Session::get('loc')}}"/>

                    <script>
                        var countries = new Bloodhound({
                            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
                            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                            limit: 10,
                            prefetch: {
                                // url points to a json file that contains an array of country names, see
                                // https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/gh-pages/data/countries.json
                                url: "<?=asset('assets/img/data2.json');?>",
                                // the json file contains an array of strings, but the Bloodhound
                                // suggestion engine expects JavaScript objects so this converts all of
                                // those strings
                                filter: function (list) {
                                    console.log(list);
                                    return $.map(list, function (country) {
                                        return {name: country};
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        countries.initialize();
                        $('#medicineSearchBar').typeahead(null, {
                            name: 'countries',
                            displayKey: 'name',
                            // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
                            // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
                            source: countries.ttAdapter()
                        });
                        jQuery('#medicineSearchBar').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum)
                        {
                            //$('#extraControls').css('display','block');

                           //console.log('kl');
                            $('#results_body').append('<tr> <td scope="row">'+$('#from_location option:selected').text()+' <br>'+$('#from_sub_location option:selected').text()+'   <\/td><td scope="row">  '+$('#to_location option:selected').text()+' <br> '+$('#to_sub_location option:selected').text()+'  <\/td><td>'+datum\['name'\]+'<\/td><td>19-05-2018<\/td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qty"></td><\/td></tr>');

                            //console.log($('#shipping_selector option:selected').text());

                        });
                    </script>
                This is data2.json 
                \["Genouillère renforcée ($30)","Genouillère Small ($20)","Genouillères XXL ($20)","Knee brace long type ($50)","Nexcare First aid Cold pack ($25)","Orthèse de stabilisation ($55)","Orthopaedic back rest long ($125)","Paire Semelle orthopodéque ($280)","Prothèse pour immobilisation ($90)","Sac de sable de 500g ($25)","Slip orthopédique ($70)"\]

alert me that it is already selected if i select the same  value of dropdown option(ie if i select Reception principale from first dropdown option and Carte de credit from second option and Genouillère renforcée ($30) from search list    ) the second time  for all three select option(including two dropdown option and one search bar) then i should display me alert .The alert should be shown on select of search bar list which is input field with id="medicineSearchBar" and above is two dropdown with id="from_sub_location" and id="to_sub_location" option which is already selected.
```

alert me that it is already selected if i select the same  value of dropdown option(ie if i select Reception principale from first dropdown option and Carte de credit from second option and Genouillère renforcée ($30) from search list    ) the second time  for all three select option(including two dropdown option and one search bar) then i should display me alert .The alert should be shown on select of search bar list which is input field with id="medicineSearchBar" and above is two dropdown with id="from_sub_location" and id="to_sub_location" option which is already selected.

Answer (score 0):

I would add onchange to the select tags to do a check on change.

**Example:**

```
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title"></label>
                            </div>
                           <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <label for="title">From Sub-location:</label>
                                <select id="from_sub_location"   class="form-control" style="width:350px" onchange="checkDropdownSelection()">
                                    <option value="0">SELECT</option>
                                    <option value="1">Reception principale</option>
                                    <option value="2">Reception Alle Maternite</option>
                                    <option value="3">Reception Alle Pediatriqui</option>
                                    <option value="4">Reception immigration</option>
                                    <option value="5">Carte de credit</option>
                                    <option value="6">2e etage</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <label for="title">To sub-location:</label>
                                <select id="to_sub_location"  class="form-control" style="width:350px" onchange="checkDropdownSelection()">
                                    <option value="0">SELECT</option>
                                    <option value="1">Reception principale</option>
                                    <option value="2">Reception Alle Maternite</option>
                                    <option value="3">Reception Alle Pediatriqui</option>
                                    <option value="4">Reception immigration</option>
                                    <option value="5">Carte de credit</option>
                                    <option value="6">2e etage</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        </div>

                <script>
                   function checkDropdownSelection() {
                      var from = document.getElementById("from_sub_location");
                      var to = document.getElementById("to_sub_location");

                      if (from.value == to.value) {
                        //The same, do something here
                      }
                   }
                </script>
```